# How to free memory in my Class destructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, boost, destructor

OK, I suppose this question may sound too silly, but memory-management (especially in C/C++) has never been my strong point and since it's usually not a noticeable thing, I tend to overlook it. So, forgive me if all this sounds stupid. However, since my current project involves A LOT of data and processing, **memory consumption easily goes above 2GB in a matter of seconds** and it definitely slows the whole thing down, so... it's time I started thinking of ways how to fix it.

---

So, here is my situation...

**My principal class** (of which I'm creating some millions of instances (which hopefully are automatically deleted, since they stop being used), so supposedly *this* is the culprit) is (roughly) this :

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        // My Constructors
        MyClass ();
        MyClass (std::string param);

        // My Destructor (still empty)
        virtual ~MyClass ();

        // Some methods
        void methodA(std::string moves);
        void methodB();

        //----------------------
        // My Variables
        //----------------------
        boost::array<int,64> arrA;
        boost::array<unsigned int,13> arrB;
        unsigned int key;

        boost::array<int,3> arrC;       
        int argA;
        int argB;
};
```

And this is (roughly - actual code has been altered) how the instances of the above class are created :

```
vector<MyClass*> SomeOtherClass::getListOfObjects()
{   
    vector<MyClass*> objects;

    for (int i=0; i<MAX_OBJS; i++)
    {
          // Do some preparatory work
          objects += new MyClass();
    }

    return objects;
}
```

And here's how the results of the above function are being used :

```
void SomeOtherClass::doSth()
{
    vector<MyClass*> objs = this->getListOfObjects();
    int objsSize = objs.size();

    for (int i=0; i<objsSize; i++)
    {
        MyClass* obj = objs[i];

        // Do sth with obj

        delete objs[i];
    }
}
```

**So, my question is :**

- What should I do in my destructor, so that when the object is not needed anymore and thus released, all of its "subcomponents" are released too? (e.g. the 2 `boost::array`s)
- Is there anything wrong you notice with the approach above?

---

Please let me know if there's anything else you need to know about my implementation...

Comment: `"it's usually not a noticeable thing, I tend to overlook it."` -- Worst attitude *ever*.  Are you familiar with the `delete` keyword?

Comment: you are missing copy/move constructors

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I know, I know; but you know how these things are...

Comment: Doesn't the question depend on whether your components are allocated on the stack or the heap?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Right, and that's the reason modern software hogs huge amounts of memory and crashes. "If something is worth doing, it's worth doing right."

Comment: @JonathonReinhart How's `delete` applicable to `boost::array`?

Comment: There is no memory to be managed in your class. How many of these `MyClass` objects are you making?

Comment: @JesseGood Around 100 millions per second (lol). True.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: I don't think any current memory allocator on current hardware could achieve that speed. Not to mention that the object has at least 336 bytes, so 100 millions are 33.6 GB and that does not fit to memory on common computer today.

Comment: @JanHudec On a common computer. Not one with a 64GB memory on it. ;-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon what's value of MAX_OBJS? and do you call getListOfObjects() a lot or just once?

Comment: @billz I don't think the answer is relevant (since the code above is an example of what the original code is), but if it matters at all it is somewhere near 12.

Comment: And how do you `delete` the objects in the `vector<MyClass*>`? BTW `std::vector` has no `operator +=`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Boost supports it (`#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>`). After the function has been called, and looped through all of the results, I either tried relooping and deleting or deleting after each iteration, but still keep getting the same error : `malloc: *** error for object 0xSOME_MEMORY_ADDRESS: pointer being freed was not allocated`.

Comment: You probably don't need a vector of pointers (use `vector<MyClass>` instead), just be careful since it's a lot more to copy (pass it by reference to `getListOfObjects` rather than returning it, which is probably a good idea in either case).

Comment: @Dukeling return by value is fine, the copy would get optimised out by named return value optimisation (NRVO). And the code would be cleaner and safer.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon after the function is called, you are copying pointers to other vector, if you iterate through it and delete again, which is UB.

Comment: @billz The initial post has been re-edited to also show how the function is called and how I'm attempting to delete the objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class members do not look to be dynamically allocated, in which case you don't need to explicitly `delete` anything in the destructor. If you *happened* to leave out some pointers to allocated memory, in this question, which you allocate with `new`, you would need to `delete` these in the destructor.

Remember, if you `new` you need to `delete`, similarly with `new[]`-`delete[]`. Barring the case of allocation to a `std::unique_ptr`.

If your `MyClass` objects themselves are allocated on the heap with `new`, then you would have to `delete` them.

p.s. if you are using C++11, you should probably use `std::array` now.

---

From your new code, it is obvious that whoever keeps the list returned from `getListOfObjects()`, needs to call `delete` on each element when its to be destroyed. It is likely the destructor of `SomeOtherClass`.

Alternatively you can wrap the `MyClass*` pointers within a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (or any of the boost smart pointers which might be relevant here) which would then delete automatically when the vector holding them goes out of scope and is destroyed.

---

If `doSth` is accurate in its representation, and ensures that ALL instances of `MyClass` get `delete`d, then this code seems fine, from a memory leak standpoint.

Comment: Hmmm... I see your point. Perhaps, you're right. Give me a sec to test it out.

Comment: I assume that you could tell they were dynamically allocated because the class members would be pointers instead, correct?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Yes thats what I was using.. let me add the caveat

Comment: this + since boost is already used... maybe using http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm

Comment: @SebbyJohanns Pointer data members does not imply dynamic allocation. You have to check whether these pointers are made to point to some memory dynamically allocated with `new` or `new[]`. Even then it isn't 100% clear who's responsibility it is to call delete. Best to avoid raw pointers in these cases and use the appropriate smart pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Another check would be that this class would have to own it, so ideally, this class would need to have allocated it.

Comment: OK, I've been trying to see what's going on with the whole thing and this the case : actually, the `MyClass` objects *are* created with a `new`, and then put in a vector. Now, whenever I try `delete`ing a `MyClass` object, once I'm done with it, I'm getting a `malloc: *** error for object 0xSOME_MEMORY_ADDRESS: pointer being freed was not allocated`. Any ideas?

Comment: @KarthikT Right, but it isn't something you can check easily from looking at a data member declaration. You need to know it (which you should, if you desinged the class), or have the documentation from the class, or make an educated guess from looking at the code.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon you might want to edit the question to show the code where you allocate and deallocate the objects and the definition of the vector, and add these details there

Comment: @juanchopanza having no pointers is good enough to infer that the destructor is free though.

Answer (score 3):

All I see is a class that correctly manages it's memory. `boost::array` is a fancy wrapper over plain old array (`boost::array<int,64> arrA` is just `int arrA[64]` with methods added to make it a random-access read-only collection for standard library algorithms) and as such is allocated as part of the object.

Now if you say you have a leak, you apparently do mismanage memory somewhere, but it's not here.

---

In modern C++, it's trend to avoid writing the deletes yourself, leaving it up to specialized destructors instead. Given the allocating code above, the [Boost.Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) might be the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

What I see is all allocated on stack. so they are being properly managed and well deleted in destructor. If there is a memory leak, may be you are calling `new MyClass` but not releasing them. or something elsewhere.

as I see in edited code there is a vector are you deleting the items of `objects` returned by  `SomeOtherClass::getListOfObjects` ?

also you may use `boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>` instead of raw pointers `MyClass*`.

Comment: "What I see is all allocated on stack" - not true... the members will be embedded where the object is created, which could be static, on the stack or on the heap.  The crucial point is that whatever memory management is applied to the object will automatically handle the members... that's where you correctly warn against `new Myclass` sans release.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit odd

> My principal class (of which I'm creating some millions of instances
>   (which hopefully are automatically deleted, since they stop being
>   used)

If you are creating instances of `MyClass` and have not done it using smart pointers of some kind then they will not magically be deleted, you need to do the job.